# IPython3: save whole session including variables

Tags: python, session, ipython, pickle

I am using the python module [kwant](https://kwant-project.org/) to create the matrices which then need to be diagonalized. This may take a lot of time, so I want to be able to save the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as well as the kwant objects that give the matrices. Using pickle, I can only save the eigenvalues and vectors but not the kwant object. My question therefore is if it is possible to save an entire session of ipython, so that all variables are assigned their exact same value as before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you serialize the `kwant` objects?

Comment: Anyway, most ways you would "save a session" would involve `pickle` in some way, but maybe you are looking for something like [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill). BTW, I was pleasantly that `kwant` wasn't yet *another* quantitative finance library.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: When i pickle kwants system object i get a type error:
can't pickle kwant.graph.core.CGraph_malloc objects
However this appears only when using jupyter with python version 3.6.0 and ipython version 5.3.0. Notebook version is 4.3.1. When i try the same notebook in Ipython3 version 1.2.1 it works somehow